# Multiple substitutions on the same file - awk

Tags: perl, replace, awk

I am trying to do multiple substitutions on the same file using an awk one-liner script.
The file that is being used for variable assignment is the following:

```
> cat names 
1 Dusky
2 Flag
3 Mon
```

and I want to do the replacement in this file:

```
> cat file.txt 
  1        1   0.6248 0.3752 
  2        2   0.0430 0.9570 
  3        3   0.0624 0.9376
```

What I have tried was:

```
while read num name; do 
    awk -v J=$num -v R=$name '{if (match($1, J)) $2=R; print;}' file.txt; 
done < names
```

but this code prints the input file for each line that is going to be replaced.

```
1 Dusky 0.6248 0.3752
  2        2   0.0430 0.9570 
  3        3   0.0624 0.9376 
  1        1   0.6248 0.3752 
2 Flag 0.0430 0.9570
  3        3   0.0624 0.9376 
  1        1   0.6248 0.3752 
  2        2   0.0430 0.9570 
3 Mon 0.0624 0.9376
```

How can I make it to print only one time the replaced lines?
Can be in awk or perl.

Desired output:

```
1 Dusky 0.6248 0.3752
2 Flag 0.0430 0.9570
3 Mon 0.0624 0.9376
```

Comment: so you want to replace the 2nd col in `file.txt` with the corresponding name in `names`? What is the separator between columns?

Comment: That's right. The separator is white space, but it can be more than one white space separating the fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about reading the first file and storing the ids? Then, replace the second field from the second file with the matched name/id.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} {$2=a[$2]; print}' names f
```

For your given input it returns:

```
1 Dusky 0.6248 0.3752
2 Flag 0.0430 0.9570
3 Mon 0.0624 0.9376
```

#### Explanation

- `FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next}` when reading the first file, store the 2nd field in an array whose index is the 1st field. This way, `1` is mapped to `Dusky`, `2` to `Flag`, ...
- `{$2=a[$2]; print}` when reading the second file, replace the 2nd field with its corresponding id in the first file. Then, print. This can be written more idiomatically as `{$2=a[$2]}1`.

---

Note you can add a security check: just replace the 2nd field on 2nd file if it really exists:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} {if ($2 in a) $2=a[$2]} 1' names f
```

Comment: You can even go shorthand and use `1` after the second action block, rather than `print`.

Comment: Great. very nice one-liner. This also showed me that I need to study more the FNR and NR variables...

Comment: @PedroA give a read to [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/). You'll find juicy things there!

Comment: Could be shortened to `awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next}$2 in a{$2=a[$2]} 1'` or Assuming the numbers are unique it could be shortened to `awk '$2 in a&&$2=a[$2];{a[$1]=$2}'`

Answer (score 3):

Using perl from command line,

```
perl -lane'
  BEGIN{ local @ARGV=pop; %h= map split,<> }
  $_ = $h{$_} //$_ for $F[1]; print "@F"
' file.txt names
```

output

```
1 Dusky 0.6248 0.3752
2 Flag 0.0430 0.9570
3 Mon 0.0624 0.9376
```

Comment: Thanks for the perl one-liner. +1

Comment: @PedroA it leaves second column unchanged if there is no number for it in `names` file.

Comment: Nice one .. I found `$_ = $h{$_} //$_ for $F[1]` a little bit cryptic in the beginning, but then I realized that `$_` is a reference in a `for` loop. So it will be equivalent to `$F[1] = $h{$F[1]} // $F[1]`..  still learning the amazing tricks in Perl :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland yes, $F[1] it is aliased/topicalized by using `for`. It _might_ be useful sometimes when dealing with long or repeating variables.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{line[$1]=$2; next} {line[$1]=line[$1]" "$3" "$4} END{for( i in line) print i, line[i]}' names file
1 Dusky 0.6248 0.3752
2 Flag 0.0430 0.9570
3 Mon 0.0624 0.9376
```